# not able to login on my website in my account

Tags: magento, authentication

I have changed the template on my website and earlier login was working very fine but after changing template login is not working after entering password it is not going through.
Even if i try to create new account even then it is not going to my account.
Please check the links shown below...

http://www.qubitinformationsystems.com/yoga/customer/account/login/

Please check i have tried these steps already...

Go to template/customer/form/login.phtml and template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml and under

add the following code in the login form

getFormKey(); ?>" />

but still same problem persists...

Code of Login.php:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By64gw5ORtRjY1FIbHVSbHpMN1E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the page code.

Please replace:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

with:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

refresh cache and check again.

Comment: check the page source, whether there is any input field which has name 'form_key' and it must have some value.

If not, then still there is some problem in pasting code.

Comment: That input field should look like:

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>" name="form_key">

Comment: via facebook icon m able to login, when i create new account m able to login but after logging out when i try to login again m not able to...

Comment: This link <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>" name="form_key"> was already their i have removed it and added again but still same situation...

Comment: Sorry

Just add <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> instead of <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>" name="form_key">

Comment: You can also do one thing. Rename your login.phtml and let magento find it from default theme.

I hope it will fix your problem

Comment: Please update your question and put file's code in here, so that I can try to help you.

Comment: I have changed the file login.php (please at /yoga/app/design/frontend/default/shoe_store/template/persistent/customer/form) the code of this page is <ul class="form-list"><li> <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?><label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label><div class="input-box">                                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />

Comment: Are you still getting same problem?

Comment: Can you update your question (do not comment) and paste source code of form tag?